# Discord.js v13 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, discord.js, typeerror

I am getting an error and I have tried everything but nothing works.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/NauticalAgonizingRegisters/index.js:12:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

Code at `index.js:12:35`

```js
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like `command.data` is `undefined`. Have a look at the files in the `commands` folder — are they all exporting a `data` object?

Comment: Hello, I only have 3 commands and only one one then are exporting a `data` object. The other two are not application commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments, it seems like you don't have a command.data.name in most of your command files. What you can do is this:

```
  for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const commandName = file.split(".")[0]
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(commandName, command);
  }
```

And/or declaring a `command.name` in each of your command file like this:

```
module.exports.name = "foobar";
```

You can use `command.name` instead of `commandName`. It doesn't matter if those other 2 files aren't application commands, as long as they have an execute (or run) function and a declaration of an exportable name variable.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724764/discord-js-v13-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-name?noredirect=1#comment126762648_71724764=), not all of your commands export a `data` object because not all of them are application commands. This means that `command.data` would be `undefined` for these commands.

You can either

- get the name of the non-application commands some other way. For example:

  ```js
  client.commands.set(command.data?.name ?? command.name, command)

  // commands/nonApplicationCommand.js
  module.exports = {
    name: 'nonApplicationCommand'
    // ...
  }
  ```
- separate your commands into separate folders for each type (this is what I would do).

  ```js
  const {readdir} = require('node:fs/promises')

  const applicationCommandFiles = await readdir('./commands/application')
  for (const file of applicationCommandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/application/${file}`);
    client.applicationCommands.set(command.data.name, command);
  }
  ```

Comment: Hello, I tried what you said but it didn't work. Don't worry though I fixed it.